# docker-registry nginx rest api

Tags: nginx, docker-registry

I am trying to build a docker-registry server from source (not as a container) on Ubuntu 14.04.1.  I was able to get most of the way there using the instructions found on digitalocean.

I am able to curl http://localhost:5000 and https://user:password@localhost:8000 with no problems

When I try to open a web browser to see hopefully more than just that, that is when the issues seem to happen.

Here is my docker-registry file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/:

```
# For versions of Nginx > 1.3.9 that include chunked transfer encoding support
# Replace with appropriate values where necessary
upstream docker-registry {
server 192.168.x.x:5000;
}
server {
listen 8000;
server_name docker-registry;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/docker-registry.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/docker-registry.key;
proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;   # required for Docker client sake
X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP
client_max_body_size 0; # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
# required to avoid HTTP 411: see Issue #1486 (https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1486)
chunked_transfer_encoding on;
location / {
 # let Nginx know about our auth file
 auth_basic              "Restricted";
 auth_basic_user_file    docker-registry.htpasswd;
proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
location /_ping {
 auth_basic off;
 proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
}
location /v1/_ping {
 auth_basic off;
 proxy_pass http://docker-registry;
 }
}
```

I have my docker registry stored locally in /var/docker-registry and ensured that it was readable by the www-data user.  Why can I not see my images on the web browser?

If I tag an image and push it to my repository it works, I can see it in the web browser:

```
https://192.168.x.x:8000/v1/repositories/ubuntu-test/tags/latest
```

I see the following:

```
 "5ba9dab47459d81c0037ca3836a368a4f8ce5050505ce89720e1fb8839ea048a"
```

When I try to get to:

```
https://192.168.x.x:8000/v1
```

Or:

```
 https://192.168.x.x:8000/v1/repositories
```

Or:

```
 https://192.168.x.x:8000/v1/images
```

I get a "not found" error

How would I be able to see everything in my /var/docker-registry folder (which is where these are stored....and yes, they are owned by the www-data user) through the web interface?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Not only is there no reason one would implement the entire url path, but there are severe security implications with implementing it.

I'm assuming you don't have much experience with web programming. There is no directory '/v1/repositories'... etc. Instead, there is a program (in this case either Python or Ruby) that is listening for the url path and has logic built-in to determine what to do.

i.e. if url = /v1/_ping: return 'ok'